# How to change the arrow icon which is displayed as the deadline indicator

Tags: ms-project

Usually the Deadline icon is shown as arrow in the Gantt Chart. It is possible to change by right clicking and selecting format.  Is it possible to show the deadline as a single line, just like "Today's line".

Comment: Hi, welcome to the Project Management site of Stack Exchange network. Just for clarification, are you asking how to change the 'deadline icon' in MS Project? or something else. It would be nice if you can add a little bit more details in your question. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Aziz for the reply.  Yes, my question was how to change the Deadline icon, which is arrow by default, to a straight line, just like "Today's Date" line.  If it is not possible if the deadline dates are different for each task, will it be possible if the dates are same for all the tasks.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. The deadline icon is a type of "Bar". Bars can only be icons. You can change many things including the icon shape and colour, but you cannot turn it into a vertical line similar to the "Today" line.

Additionally Deadlines apply on a per-task basis and it does not make any difference if all tasks have the same deadline date.

Perhaps you may be able to achieve the same result by adding a Milestone task called Deadline at the top level, and allowing that milestone to appear on the Timeline along with other key tasks?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw vertical lines on the Gantt chart using the drawing toolbar.  Click the Gantt Chart tools format ribbon and click drawing.  Hold down your Shift key while drawing the line (to make sure it is plumb).  Then right click the line and attach to the timescale date.